# mapStateToProps is not calling when same route is called again

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga, mapstatetoprops

> Firstly, I'm using `"react": "^16.13.0",` functional components only, not classes, along with

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.0", "react-router": "^5.2.0", "redux": "^4.0.5", "redux-saga": "^1.1.3", "webpack": "^4.42.0",
```

I've 2 components in react component - `landingPage.js` which gets the favorite values from localStorage and stores it to redux-store on initial render.
When I navigate to favorites component, it calls the `mapDispatchToProps`, fetches the `favsList` values from store -> selector and renders the list.

When I try to hit the favorites (same component) button while still being in favorites, `mapStateToProps` is not getting called and so not rendering the `favsList`. While I still see the state intact in redux store, not changed.

**> Question 1:**
If the state doesn't changes (here if favsList is not updated) mapStateToProps won't get called? If yes, why is it working when I'm coming back from `landingPage.js` to `favorites.js` and not from `favorites.js` to `favorites.js`?

**> Question 2:** What's the alternate way to trigger `mapStateToProps` on initial component render?

> EDIT adding code snippets:

Here's the landingPage:

```html
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchItemDetailsRequest, saveItemToFavSuccess } from '../Services/actions';
import { lastCatRouteSelector, favListSelector } from '../Services/selectors';
import Home from '../Components/Common/home';

function Home({
    itemData,
    dispatchItemData,
    handleSwitch,
    selectedLanguage,
    dispatchSetInitialFavList,
}) {


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatchSetInitialFavList();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={coreStyles.mainContent}>
            <Home />
        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    itemData: lastCatRouteSelector(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    dispatchItemData: () => {
        dispatch(fetchItemListRequest());
    },
    dispatchSetInitialFavList: () => {
        dispatch(saveItemToFavSuccess());
    },
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DLJHome);
```

In the above you I want you to see at the

```
dispatchSetInitialFavList: () => {
            dispatch(saveItemToFavSuccess());
        },
```

which saves the favList to store. The corresponding actions.js

```html
export const saveItemToFavSuccess = (itemId, fetchedItems) => {
        let favList = !localStorage.getItem('favList')
            ? []
            : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favList')).length > 1
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favList'))
            : [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favList'))[0]];

        itemId ? favList.push(itemId.toString()) : null;

        localStorage.setItem('favList', JSON.stringify(favList));
        return {
            type: SAVE_ITEM_TO_FAV_SUCCESS,
            payload: fetchedItems ? [favList, fetchedItems] : [favList],
        };
    };
```

- sagas.js:

```html
function* saveItemToFav() {
    yield takeEvery(SAVE_ITEM_TO_FAV_REQUEST, saveItemToFavRequest);
}

function* saveItemToFavRequest(action) {
    try {
        const itemId = action.payload;
        const existingFavs = yield select(favListSelector);
        yield put(saveItemToFavSuccess([itemId]));
    } catch (saveFavError) {
        console.warn('Error occured while saving to fav', saveFavError);
    }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([fetchItemDetails(), saveCatRoute(), saveItemToFav(), saveItemRoute()]);
}
```

- reducers.js

```html
function saveItemToFavReduer(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_ITEM_TO_FAV_SUCCESS:
            return { favList: deducePayload(action) };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const itemCategoryReducer = combineReducers({
    favList: saveItemToFavReduer,
});
const deducePayload = (action) => {
    return action.payload;
};
export default itemCategoryReducer;
```

And finally, here's the

- favorites.js
  where the  `console.log('inFavs', favList);` returns empty/null array

```html
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { itemDetailsSelector, favListSelector } from '../../Services/selectors';
import { saveItemToFavReduer } from '../../Services/reducers';

function Favorites({ favList, itemDetails, dispatchFetchItemData }) {
    console.log('inFavs', favList);
);
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    favList: state.favList,
    itemDetails: state.itemDetails ? state.itemDetails : [],
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    dispatchFetchItemData: (itemId) => {
        dispatch(fetchItemDetailsRequest(itemId));
    },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Favorites);
```

- App.js

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IntlProvider, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import messages from './Core/i18n';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components';
import Favorites from './Components/Common/favorites';

function App() {
const [locale, setLocale] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem('localValue') ? localStorage.getItem('localValue') : 'en',
    );
    const handleSwitch = (language) => {
        setLocale(language);
        localStorage.setItem('localValue', language);
    };
    return (
        <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages[locale]}>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    exact={true}
                    path="/"
                    component={() => <Home handleSwitch={handleSwitch} selectedLanguage={locale} />}
                />
                <Route
                    exact={true}
                    path="/home"
                    component={() => <Home handleSwitch={handleSwitch} selectedLanguage={locale} />}
                />
                <Route path="/categories/" component={ItemCategory} />
                <Route path="/favorites/" component={Favorites} />
            </Switch>
        </IntlProvider>
    );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

- index.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import 'core-js/stable';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './Services/store';

const title = 'Title';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <App title={title} />
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
);

module.hot.accept();
```

Comment: can you share some code snippets as well? That might help in understanding what is your current approach and what needs to be done

Comment: @DineshNadimpalli added code for your reference

Comment: Can you join this chat room to discuss more in detail https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218212/discussion-on-issue-62982905